# How to set minimal distance between nodes in dot for FDP rendering?

Tags: graphviz, dot

So I try [this tool](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/) to render my dot file in FDP mode and I get:

[image]

from such source:

```
digraph G {
subgraph place {
node [shape=circle,fixedsize=true,label=" ",height=.3,width=.3];
FatTree_DecomposedMarks [xlabel = "DecomposedMarks"];
FatTree_Nodes_0 [xlabel = "Nodes_0"];
FatTree_Nodes_1 [xlabel = "Nodes_1"];
FatTree_Nodes_2 [xlabel = "Nodes_2"];
FatTree_Nodes_3 [xlabel = "Nodes_3"];
FatTree_Nodes_4 [xlabel = "Nodes_4"];
FatTree_Nodes_5 [xlabel = "Nodes_5"];
FatTree_Nodes_6 [xlabel = "Nodes_6"];
FatTree_Nodes_7 [xlabel = "Nodes_7"];
FatTree_Nodes_8 [xlabel = "Nodes_8"];
FatTree_Nodes_9 [xlabel = "Nodes_9"];
FatTree_Nodes_10 [xlabel = "Nodes_10"];
FatTree_Nodes_11 [xlabel = "Nodes_11"];
FatTree_Nodes_12 [xlabel = "Nodes_12"];
FatTree_Nodes_13 [xlabel = "Nodes_13"];
FatTree_Nodes_14 [xlabel = "Nodes_14"];
FatTree_Nodes_15 [xlabel = "Nodes_15"];
FatTree_Nodes_16 [xlabel = "Nodes_16"];
FatTree_Nodes_17 [xlabel = "Nodes_17"];
FatTree_Nodes_18 [xlabel = "Nodes_18"];
FatTree_Nodes_19 [xlabel = "Nodes_19"];
FatTree_Nodes_20 [xlabel = "Nodes_20"];
FatTree_Nodes_21 [xlabel = "Nodes_21"];
FatTree_Nodes_22 [xlabel = "Nodes_22"];
FatTree_Nodes_23 [xlabel = "Nodes_23"];
FatTree_Nodes_24 [xlabel = "Nodes_24"];
FatTree_Nodes_25 [xlabel = "Nodes_25"];
FatTree_Nodes_26 [xlabel = "Nodes_26"];
FatTree_Nodes_27 [xlabel = "Nodes_27"];
FatTree_Nodes_28 [xlabel = "Nodes_28"];
FatTree_Nodes_29 [xlabel = "Nodes_29"];
FatTree_Nodes_30 [xlabel = "Nodes_30"];
FatTree_Nodes_31 [xlabel = "Nodes_31"];
FatTree_Nodes_32 [xlabel = "Nodes_32"];
FatTree_Nodes_33 [xlabel = "Nodes_33"];
FatTree_Nodes_34 [xlabel = "Nodes_34"];
FatTree_Nodes_35 [xlabel = "Nodes_35"];
FatTree_Nodes_36 [xlabel = "Nodes_36"];
FatTree_Nodes_37 [xlabel = "Nodes_37"];
FatTree_Nodes_38 [xlabel = "Nodes_38"];
FatTree_Nodes_39 [xlabel = "Nodes_39"];
FatTree_Nodes_40 [xlabel = "Nodes_40"];
FatTree_Nodes_41 [xlabel = "Nodes_41"];
FatTree_Nodes_42 [xlabel = "Nodes_42"];
FatTree_Nodes_43 [xlabel = "Nodes_43"];
FatTree_Nodes_44 [xlabel = "Nodes_44"];
FatTree_Nodes_45 [xlabel = "Nodes_45"];
FatTree_Nodes_46 [xlabel = "Nodes_46"];
FatTree_Nodes_47 [xlabel = "Nodes_47"];
FatTree_Nodes_48 [xlabel = "Nodes_48"];
FatTree_Nodes_49 [xlabel = "Nodes_49"];
FatTree_Nodes_50 [xlabel = "Nodes_50"];
FatTree_Nodes_51 [xlabel = "Nodes_51"];
FatTree_Nodes_52 [xlabel = "Nodes_52"];
FatTree_Nodes_53 [xlabel = "Nodes_53"];
FatTree_Routers_0_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_0_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_1_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_2_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_3_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_4_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_5_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_6_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_7_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_8_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_9_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_10_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_11_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_12_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_13_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_14_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_15_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_16_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_17_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_18_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_19_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_20_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_21_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_22_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_23_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_24_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_25_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_26_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_27_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_28_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_29_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_30_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_31_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_32_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_33_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_34_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_35_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_36_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_37_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_38_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_39_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_40_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_41_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_42_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_43_58225482"];
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 [xlabel = "Routers_44_58225482"];
}
subgraph transitions  {
node [shape=rect,height=.4,width=.1,label="",fillcolor=black, style=filled];
}
FatTree_Nodes_0 -> FatTree_Routers_0_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_1 -> FatTree_Routers_0_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_2 -> FatTree_Routers_0_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_3 -> FatTree_Routers_1_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_4 -> FatTree_Routers_1_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_5 -> FatTree_Routers_1_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_6 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_7 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_8 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_9 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_10 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_11 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_12 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_13 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_14 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_15 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_16 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_17 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_18 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_19 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_20 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_21 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_22 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_23 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_24 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_25 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_26 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_27 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_28 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_29 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_30 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_31 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_32 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_33 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_34 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_35 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_36 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_37 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_38 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_39 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_40 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_41 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_42 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_43 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_44 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_45 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_46 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_47 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_48 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_49 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_50 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_51 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_52 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Nodes_53 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_0_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_0;
FatTree_Routers_0_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_1;
FatTree_Routers_0_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_2;
FatTree_Routers_0_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_3;
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_4;
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_5;
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_1_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_6;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_7;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_8;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_2_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_9;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_10;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_11;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_3_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_12;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_13;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_14;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_4_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_15;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_16;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_17;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_5_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_18;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_19;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_20;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_6_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_21;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_22;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_23;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_7_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_24;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_25;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_26;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_8_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_27;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_28;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_29;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_9_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_30;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_31;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_32;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_10_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_33;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_34;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_35;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_11_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_36;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_37;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_38;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_12_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_39;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_40;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_41;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_13_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_42;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_43;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_44;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_14_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_45;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_46;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_47;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_15_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_48;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_49;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_50;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_16_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_51;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_52;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Nodes_53;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_17_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_0_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_1_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_18_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_1_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_19_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_2_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_20_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_3_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_21_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_4_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_22_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_5_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_23_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_6_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_24_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_7_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_25_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_8_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_26_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_9_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_27_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_10_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_28_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_11_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_29_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_12_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_30_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_13_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_31_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_14_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_32_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_15_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_36_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_39_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_33_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_42_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_16_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_37_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_40_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_34_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_43_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_17_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_38_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_41_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_35_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_44_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_36_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_37_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_38_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_39_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_40_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_41_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_18_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_21_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_24_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_27_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_30_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_42_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_33_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_19_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_22_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_25_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_28_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_31_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_43_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_34_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_20_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_23_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_26_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_29_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_32_58225482;
FatTree_Routers_44_58225482 -> FatTree_Routers_35_58225482;
}
```

In perfect world It would look a little more like [this fat tree with Tree Depth set to 3 and
Ports per Switch set to 6](https://fs.linkmeup.ru/ftree-vis/index.html), yet FDP is more or less OK... Only thing I want to change is the mess in the centre: How to set minimal distance between nodes in dot for FDP rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you add this after the first line, it seems to help:
  **graph[K=3. sep="+16"]**